# Can not login and how to redirect different level user to each member area page

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm a novice in CodeIgniter. I'm trying to make multi-level user login in CodeIgniter, but still failed to login, always going back to the login page. And I want to redirect every level user to each member area page.

here is my controller member.php:

```
    class Member extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->model('account_model');
    }
    function login(){
        $form_data = $this->input->post('data');
        if(!empty($form_data))
        {
            if($this->account_model->login($form_data['username'], $form_data['password']))
            {
                redirect('member/index');
            } else {
                redirect('member/login');
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('login');      
    }
}
```

model account_model.php :

```
    class Account_model extends CI_Model{
    private $table = 'akun';

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function login($username, $password, $level){
        $data = $this->db->where(array('username'=> $username, 'password'=> $password, 'level'=> $level))->get($this->table);



    if($data->num_rows() > 0){
        $akun = $data->row();        

        $session = array(
            'logged_in' => 1,
            'username' =>$akun->username,
            'level' =>$akun->level,         

        );


        $this->session->set_userdata($session);
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('notification', 'Username and Password not match');
        return false;
    }
}
```

view login.php :

```
<?php echo form_open('member/login') ?>
<div class="input">
  <?php
  echo form_label('Username');
  echo form_input('data[username]');
  =?>
 </div>
 <div class="input">
   <?php
   echo form_label('Password');
   echo form_password('data[password]');
   ?>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
  <?php
   echo form_submit('login', 'Login');
  ?>
  </div>
  <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

And here is my table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `akun` (
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `level` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have a page called member.php in application/views for the member area. but I can't redirect to that page from login. Also, I still don't know how to redirect different level user to each member area. I hope someone can solve my problem.

Comment: what does this resolve to: form_open('member/login') - you sure that path is being written correctly?

Comment: @KaiQing i'm pretty sure i've written it correctly as the tutorial i've followed. i just knew that path was ('controller/function'). Can you please tell me where is my mistake? thx

Comment: You have multiple problems in your code including the line `echo form_password('data[password]');`. You are not passing any data to your view and still trying to display it. Not to mention the syntax is wrong. To pass data to a view, try this: `$this->load->view('login',$data);` and make sure $data has proper data in it. However, this is just one problem. You need to read the CI user guide much more thoroughly than you already have done so.

Comment: @NaveedHasan Why not suggest a fix in the form of an answer to his actual problem?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Ok, good idea... I initially didn't do that because I thought this is a just a suggestion... but I guess now I will post it as an answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code including the line

```
echo form_password('data[password]');
```

You are not passing any data to your view and still trying to display it. Not to mention the syntax is wrong. To pass data to a view, try this:

```
$this->load->view('login',$data);
```

and make sure $data has proper data in it. However, this is just one problem. You need to read the CI user guide much more thoroughly than you already have done so.